# MySQL Return Job Title and Department Name of an employee

Tags: mysql, sql

> Write a select statement that returns the job title and the department name of Jennifer Whalen

My Code Written in MySQL as an HR

```
SELECT JOB_TITLE 
FROM JOBS
WHERE JOB_TITLE IN (
    SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME 
    FROM departments
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME IN (
        SELECT  FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES
        WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'Jennifer' AND LAST_NAME = 'Whalen'
    )
);
```

My Error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with `EXISTS.

I'd appreciate any feedback or help!

Table diagrams:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245136/discussion-on-question-by-lawrence-mysql-return-job-title-and-department-name-of).

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to figure it out turns out I was trying to work on a practice question that we haven't been taught yet!

```
FROM Employees e Inner Join Departments d
ON e.department_ID = d.Department_ID
Inner Join Jobs j
ON e.Job_ID = j.Job_ID
WHERE First_Name Like 'Jennifer' AND Last_Name LIKE 'Whalen';
```